# Ori assembly mips

Tags: assembly, mips

Why use "ori" in this code?

```
#case 3:
switch02_code_3 :
#a [ 5 ] = 50000;
ori $t0 , $zero , 0xC350        # $t0 <− 0x0000C350 = 50000
la $t1 , a                      # $t1 <− base address from a
sw $t0 , 20($t1)                # a [ 5 ] = 50000
#break;
j switch02_end                  # finish switch block
```

I don't see why it is necessary to expand the number of bits

Comment: Please, post text as text, not as photographs of text. This is a website for programmers, not photographers. We want to copy&paste&run your code, copy&paste your inputs, read your outputs, and copy&paste&google your error messages, not critique your use of color and perspective. Also, please make sure to post everything relevant to answering your question *in your question*, not behind a link. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2988 https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: `ori` is there to materialize a constant in a register.  MIPS doesn't have a store-immediate, `sw` is an I-type instruction that uses the immediate bits as a displacement for the addressing-mode.  Unless you want to store a zero from `$zero`, or some other value you already have in a register, you need an instruction to get the value into a register.  It could be outside a loop so you don't have to keep redoing it, but you haven't shown enough context to include any missed optimizations.

Comment: The `ori` instruction zero-extends its 16-bit immediate, whereas `addi` sign extends its 16-bit immediate.  So, `ori` can handle an immediate from 0 to 65535 whereas `addi` can handle an immediate from -32768 to 32767.

Answer (score 2):

That line is `li $t0,0xC350`. The `li` instruction isn't real, it uses `addi` or `ori` to do the job. Since `0xC350` exceeds `0x7FFF`, using `addi` would result in sign-extension which wasn't what the programmer wrote in the source code (most likely `li $t0,0xC350`)